# Count number of times a level occurs within a cluster/group in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, cluster-computing

I have a dataframe with clusters. In this dataframe, I want to count the number of times a particular value occurs inside a cluster. For example:

```
data = {'cluster':['1001', '1001', '1001', '1002', '1002', '1002'],
        'attribute':['1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

I want to count how many times '1' has occurred inside each cluster. I have tried using lambda functions, and although trying to average inside the cluster works, count is not working.

For averaging, I used:

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby('cluster')['attribute'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
df
```

Using the same, but with mean replaced with count:

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby('cluster')['attribute'].transform(lambda x: x.count('2'))
df
```

Gives me this error:

> Error: 'Requested level (3) does not match index name (None)'

I ideally want to add the count as an additional column, hence am using the lambda function.

Please help me in solving this! If any additional detail is required or if I was not clear, I'd be happy to add information!

**Edit**

Thank you, @Rutger has provided what I was looking for. In a gist, I was looking to create a new column that would show me how many times the attribute has occurred in a cluster. I also needed it to be generalizable, so that all the attributes could be calculated.

On a separate note, my dataframe consists of around 600,000 rows. Is there a recommended way to perhaps take a chunk out of this dataset so that I could do my work on that? If there's a similar answer somewhere else, kindly point me towards the same! Thank you!

Comment: The "averaging" and "replaced with count" code blocks are the same. Can you update your question to include what your count code looked like?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I missed that. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it. I would go for a groupby with both columns and then you just see how frequent they occur. This is not the most straightforward method I assume but I think it's the result you are looking for.

```
df['count'] = df.set_index(['cluster', 'attribute']).index.map(df.groupby(['cluster', 'attribute']).size())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, but I think I was not able to express clearly what I needed. Thanks for reading between the lines!

Comment: Welcome! It's sometimes difficult to express it. When I first saw you question I thought you simply wanted the value counts of each pair but then saving it as an extra column is the tricky part. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add a column alongside with the existing columns to show the number of `1's` in a cluster (group), you can keep on using `.transform()` as you are doing now.

Inside the `.transform()`, you can use lambda function to check the elements equal '1' and get the `sum()` (instead of count) of such `True` entries, as follows:

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby('cluster')['attribute'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('1').sum())
```

Result:

```
print(df)


  cluster attribute   newcol
0    1001         1        2
1    1001         2        2
2    1001         1        2
3    1002         1        1
4    1002         2        1
5    1002         2        1
```

Comment: This works well, but I am not sure how to generalize it. For example, if I want the new column to represent how many times '1' has occurred within the cluster corresponding to the '1' attribute row, and how many times '2' has occurred within the cluster corresponding to the '2' attribute row, I do not know how to generalize this answer.

This is why the answer provided by @Rutger is the most useful to me. Thank you nonetheless!